# Python if else conditions when date gets changed

Tags: python, pandas, date, conditional-statements

I have a python code in which I need to compare entered date with existing pandas Date column and get index number of that rows. But if that date doesn't exist then it should get index number of rows of exact previous dates. Example of code and dataframe is given below.

Dataframe:-

```
 SR.No     Date
  1      01-12-2013
  1      01-12-2014
  1      01-12-2015
  1      01-12-2016
  1      01-12-2017 
  1      01-12-2018
  1      01-12-2019
  1      01-12-2020 
  1      01-12-2013
  1      01-12-2014
  1      01-12-2015
  1      01-12-2016
  1      01-12-2017 
  1      01-12-2018
  1      01-12-2019
  1      01-12-2020 
  2      01-12-2013
  2      01-12-2014
  2      01-12-2015
  2      01-12-2016
  2      01-12-2017
  2      01-12-2018
  2      01-12-2019 
  2      01-12-2020 
  2      01-12-2013
  2      01-12-2014
  2      01-12-2015
  2      01-12-2016
  2      01-12-2017
  2      01-12-2018
  2      01-12-2019 
  2      01-12-2020
```

**Code:-**

```
date = '01-06-2018'
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],dayfirst=True)
date = pd.to_datetime(date,dayfirst=True)
if df['Date'].eq(date).any():
    _index =  df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
else:
    date = (date - pd.DateOffset(months=6))
    _index =  df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
```

But in case we change input date from `'01-06-2018'` to `'01-09-2018'` or `'01-03-2018'`. Then it also should become only **01-12-2017** using `DateOffset(months=3)` and `DateOffset(months=9)` respectively and should get me the index number of 01-12-2017.

> So how can we do that using if elif else conditions? Or using any other way?

Comment: Please post code to initialze the dataframe so that we can work with and post working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the largest date less than the given date:

```
date = df[df['Date'] <= date]['Date'].max()                                                                                                                                                     
index = df[df['Date'] == date].index
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I got my output using this code.